# SEO dinâmico funciona?

Tags: seo

Estou estudando SEO, e vi que para determinados assuntos, usamos microformatos diferentes, para a identificação e rankeamento das páginas, porém, me ocorreu uma dúvida, pesquisei em vários lugares mas não encontrei uma resposta clara e objetiva.
Alterar os microformatos dinamicamente de acordo com o conteúdo a ser apresentado, é funcional, semântico e viável ? Por exemplo, alterar com o php os valores e atributos de microformatos usados de acordo com o conteúdo da página, sem ter algum tipo de problema ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Alterar os microformatos dinamicamente de acordo com o conteúdo a ser
>   apresentado, é funcional, semântico e viável ?

Independente de seu conteúdo ser dinâmico ou estático, para cada página vão existir microformatos diferentes, se você tiver formas de automatizar esse retorno para o usuário, torna-se indiferente a forma que faça, desde que não prejudique desempenho, qualidade e usabilidade pro usuário final/mecanismo de indexação.

> ... alterar com o php os valores e atributos de microdados usados de
>   acordo com o conteúdo da página, sem ter algum tipo de problema ?

Microdados usam um vocabulário de apoio para descrever um item e pares **nome-valor** para atribuir valores às suas propriedades. Microdados ajudam tecnologias como motores de busca e crawlers a entender melhor quais informações estão contidas em uma página web... Levando isso em conta, acredito que quanto mais dinamismo, para que esses pares de nome-valor sejam preenchidos corretamente, melhor seria visto aos mecanismos.

Answer (score 1):

O assunto é complexo e controverso, mas não é muito difícil de entender. Seguem minhas considerações.

Vou dividir o assunto em duas partes, a primeira é pra vc avaliar se vale a penas gastar esse tempo e esforço, e a segunda é para esclarecer uns pontos caso vc siga com o projeto.

Só para esclarecer e evitar confusões *não vamos confundir Microdata com Data Estrutirada*.

- **Data estruturada** é: É um sistema de parear Nome com Valor que ajuda os motores a categorzar e indexar seu conteúdo.
- **Microdata** é: É uma forma de estruturar o Dado de forma que funcione no HTML5

*Agora vamos aos fatos!*

> **Structured data's effect on rankings**
>
> Whether structured data affects rankings has been the subject of much
>   discussion and many experiments. As of yet, there is no conclusive
>   evidence that this markup improves rankings. But there are some
>   indications that search results with more extensive rich snippets
>   (like those created using Schema) will have a better click-through
>   rate. For best results, experiment with Schema markup to see how your
>   audience responds to the resulting rich snippets.

Fonte: https://moz.com/learn/seo/schema-structured-data

> **Google’s John Mueller** recently stated that the search engine giant may
>   add structured data markup as a ranking factor. So it is definitely
>   worth the effort to implement schema markup on your website, as this
>   is becoming more important to Google.

Fonte: https://searchengineland.com/schema-markup-structured-data-seo-opportunities-site-type-231077

Resumindo... **NÃO há comprovação alguma que Schema ou qualquer rich snippet e Data Estruturada influencie no seu ranqueamento por si só!**

O que a Data Estruturada faz e indexar melhor o seu conteúdo na pesquisa, ela vai deixar o seu conteúdo mais completo e fácil de ser encontrado, mas *não vai levar seu site para o topo das buscas.*

O que o próprio **Google** da a entender é que um conteúdo rico tem mais chance de ser clicado, com isso se as suas informações forem mais completas seu link vai ser mais clicado e com isso o seu rankeamento pode melhor.

O que ele quer dizer é que o seu link vai aparecer assim, no meio da busca, e que por ser mais completo tem mais chance de ser clicado.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fonte: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/intro-structured-data

*(Esse link tem várias recomendações do Google sobre o assunto, inclusive fala para usar o formato JSON e seguir o Guia de Boas Práticas de Data Estruturada)*

> **Caso queira seguir com o projeto aqui vão alguns links**

**Documentação Schema:** https://schema.org/docs/gs.html

**Padrão W3C:** https://www.w3.org/TR/microdata/#introduction

**Guia do Google:** https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/sd-policies

**Ferramenta para testar sua Data Estruturada:** https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool

E respondendo "...é funcional, semântico e viável..." Sim é funcional, Sim é semântico. Acredito que sim, mas depende do seu, tempo, dinheiro, e paciência para ver seu rankemanto subir.