# Usar h3 para título do produto na vitrine

Tags: html, seo

Eu tenho umas lista de produtos onde eu coloco o nome deles dentro de um span usando o `itemprop="name"` do [Schema.org](https://schema.org/Product) para definir que esse é o nome do produto, mas uma agência de marketing do meu cliente entrou em contato comigo me informando que essa técnica de colocar o `itemprop` dentro de um span é incorreto e o certo seria colocar dentro de um h3. Verifiquei nos maiores e-commerce e a maioria usa h2 e tem até alguns que usam h1 para definir o título dos produtos.

Esse é o meu cliente:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não sou familiarizado com o atributo, mas conforme [esta documentação](https://www.w3.org/TR/microdata/), me parece que a pessoa que te disse isso está um pouco equivocada.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sup>Eu ia escrever como comentário, mas ficou grande de mais e vai como resposta mesmo, apesar de ser controverso isso até onde sei</sup>

Primeiro seria legal entender a diferença entre `Microdata` e `Data Estruturada` isso vai te ajudar a entender o conteiro e outras informações. [SEO dinâmico funciona?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/263196/seo-din%C3%A2mico-funciona/263254#263254)

Sobre o uso de H3 ele realmente tem mais peso semântico. Aqui tem um artigo que vai te ajudar a entender

> *"As Heading Tags (H1, H2, H3, ...) são recursos de programação HTML utilizados para destacar títulos e sub-títulos de uma página. H1 é a abreviação do inglês para Header 1, ou Cabeçalho 1, logo, o mais importante dos Headers."*

`Fonte:` https://www.seomarketing.com.br/heading-tags-h1-h2-h3-seo.php

**OBS:** Já se discutiu muito que cada página deveria ter apenas um H1 etc, mas não existe nada concreto que confirme essa "teoria". Leitura recomendada https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/the-truth-about-multiple-h1-tags-in-the-html5-era--webdesign-16824

Apesar disso tudo sobre os Headres nada indica que o Google os use como fator de ranqueamento, e eles estão mais associados a semântica e acessibilidade do que com SEO.

---

**Sobre o `itemprop`**

Essa tag é bem nova e ela faz parte dos Drafts do HTML, porém e bem documentada tanto pela W3C quando Schema.org

Veja o que a Mozilla fala sobre o `itemprop`

> *"O atributo global  itemprop é usado para adicionar propriedades para um item. Todo elemento HTML pode ter um atributo itemprop  especificado ...  e pode ser associada a uma grande variedade de elementos incluindo `<audio>, <embed>, <iframe>, <img>, <link>, <object>, <source> , <track>`, e`<video>`."*

Fonte: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/itemprop

E como vc pode ver no próprio exemplo de itempro do Schema.org eles usar a tag em um simples `span` e mais uma vez n**ão há nada indicando que devem ser usados em H1 ou H2 ou H3**... https://schema.org/docs/gs.html#microdata_itemprop

```
<div itemscope itemtype ="http://schema.org/Movie">
  <h1 itemprop="name">Avatar</h1>
  <span>Director: <span itemprop="director">James Cameron</span> (born August 16, 1954)</span>
  <span itemprop="genre">Science fiction</span>
  <a href="../movies/avatar-theatrical-trailer.html" itemprop="trailer">Trailer</a>
</div>
```

**Dica 1:** Documentação das tags usadas para construir o *Rich Snippet* de produtos da Schema https://schema.org/Product *(não há menção aos headers)*

**Dica 2:** *Ferramenta da Google* para testar suas Datas Estruturadas https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool

**Dica 3:** Construindo Data Estruturada com o `JSON-LD`, artigo do Google: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/intro-structured-data?hl=pt-br *(não há menção aos headers)*

Comment: Resumindo: não se usa `<h3>` porque é certo, mas sim quando o contexto semântico do HTML exigir.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss basicamente eh por ai mesmo, h3 realmente seria mais adequado que um span, mas falando em seo não da para afirmar nada... Como na maioria das coisas, quando se fala de seo o assunto eh obscuro rs, mas tbm não há nada de incorreto em colocar itemprop em um span...